# How to increment a variable after 1 second in javascript

Tags: javascript, return

The goal is to add 1 every second.  I am not sure about how to use `return` here, and how  to `return` the value of *secsUp* to *seconds*.

```
function timeDisp ()
{
var seconds=0;
function changeSecs ()
    {
        var secsUp = seconds+1;
        return secsUp;
    }
document.write(seconds);
}
setInterval(timeDisp,1000);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problems with your code

1. You have declared a local variable `seconds=0` in timeDisp() So the value of seconds will always reset to 0 whenever this method is called.
2. You are not calling `changeSecs()` method anytime. I don't see any use of it if you just want to increase 1 to your seconds variable.

Try this [jsbin Demo](http://jsbin.com/cuqid/3/edit?html,js,output)

```
var seconds=0;
function timeDisp() {
  seconds++;
  document.write(seconds);
}
setInterval(timeDisp,1000);
```

Comment: Nit: `document.write` should not be used and is unreliable here (it will act different on different browsers as it "re-opens" the document stream, for whatever that is taken to mean).

Comment: @user2864740 Yes you are absolutely right. I just didn't mention it in my answer considering it out of topic. Now I realize I should have added it as 3rd point.

Answer (score 1):

you should store the value of secsUp, in another variable , which is called outside the function. eg- int a= changeSecs(); it will hold the value being returned